# Why is my button not working in Swift Playgrounds?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift-playground

I am trying to make a playground and I have a button that says "Let's play!" and moves into a new view controller.

I looked at the code from this website and put it into my code:

http://lab.dejaworks.com/ios-swift-3-playground-uibutton-action/

This is all of my code (like, all of it):

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {

        //Introduction



        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red


        //title

        func labelCool() {

        let label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 300, width: 400, height: 100)
        label.text = "Add-Add - A Wonderful Game!"
        //label.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 20)
        label.numberOfLines = 3
        label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 30)

        UILabel.animate (withDuration: 10.0, animations:{
            label.textColor = .black
        })
        UILabel.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations:{
            label.textColor = .blue
        })
        view.addSubview(label)

        }

        labelCool()

        //subtitle
        let subtitle = UILabel()
        subtitle.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 400, width: 200, height: 50)
        subtitle.text = "Curated and Created by Yours Truly, Adit Dayal!"
        subtitle.numberOfLines = 4
        self.view = view
        view.addSubview(subtitle)




    }

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        class Responder : NSObject {
            @objc func action() {
                print("Yay!")
            }
        }


        let responder = Responder()

        //next page
        let button = UIButton(frame : CGRect(x: 0, y: 500, width: 200, height: 50))
        button.setTitle("Let's Play!", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .blue
        button.addTarget(responder, action: #selector(Responder.action), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)
    }

}

class gameViewController: UIViewController {

}







// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

For now, I just want the button to display "Yay!" when clicked, but it is doing nothing!
Does anyone know why? (I'm on a bit of a time constraint)

Thank you so much,

Adit Dayal

Comment: Your Responder class is inside of your viewDidLoad()

Comment: Did my answer help you? If yes, can you mark as best?

Answer (score 0):

Your Responder class is inside the viewDidLoad() function put the class outside like so

```
class Responder : NSObject {
    @objc func action() {
        print("Yay!")
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let responder = Responder()

    //next page
    let button = UIButton(frame : CGRect(x: 0, y: 500, width: 200, height: 50))
    button.setTitle("Let's Play!", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .blue
    button.addTarget(responder, action: #selector(responder.action), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)
}
```

Comment: Hi! So I tried this, yet still nothing is happening... any idea as to why?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating the responder object inside the `viewDidLoad`, as a local variable; this cause the object to be destroyed when the function ends (but we want that object alive even after). You have to retain that object, so instead of creating a local variable, create an instance variable by simply saving it as a class scope:

```
class Responder : NSObject {
    @objc func action() {
        print("Yay!")
    }
}

let responder = Responder() // this is now outside the viewDidLoad, so it's an instance variable

override func viewDidLoad() {
    //next page
    let button = UIButton(frame : CGRect(x: 0, y: 500, width: 200, height: 50))
    button.setTitle("Let's Play!", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .blue
    button.addTarget(responder, action: #selector(Responder.action), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)
}
```